# How to send a message only after a message.delete() timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send the `message.channel.send('Send me after timeout');` **only after** the message.delete() timeout.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'coin',
    description: 'Toss Coin!',
    aliases: 'toss',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.delete().catch(O_o => {});

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setTitle(`${message.author.username}`)
        .setColor('#6d00c1')
        .setImage('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/06/04/8f0604aedc34d33d2f41113c312a588d.gif');
        
        message.channel.send(embed)
        .then(message => { message.delete({ timeout: 4000 })}).catch(O_o => {});

        message.channel.send('Send me after timeout');
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done like this:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
      .then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 4000 }).then(m => m.channel.send("Send me after timeout"))).catch(O_o => {});
```